# Ошибка при установке guard-livereload

Tags: cmd, gems

```
gem install guard-livereload
```

> ERROR: Error installing guard-livereload:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem
>   native extension.
>
> "C:/Program Files/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe" -r
>   ./siteconf20160513-4972-mbp2zq.rb extconf.rb creating Makefile

```
make "DESTDIR=" clean
```

> 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

```
make "DESTDIR="
```

> 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.
>
> make failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in C:/Program
>   Files/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for
>   inspection. Results logged to C:/Program
>   Files/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out

Почему возникает ошибка и что делать?